# I want to calculate the max GDP column in a data frame using panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame

```
    Unnamed: 0  COUNTRY GDP (BILLIONS)  CODE
0   0   Afghanistan 21.71   AFG
1   1   Albania 13.40   ALB
2   2   Algeria 227.80  DZA
3   3   American Samoa  0.75    ASM
4   4   Andorra 4.80    AND
... ... ... ... ...
217 217 Virgin Islands  5.08    VGB
218 218 West Bank   6.64    WBG
219 219 Yemen   45.45   YEM
220 220 Zambia  25.61   ZMB
221 221 Zimbabwe    13.74   ZWE
```

I would like to know how I can output the Max and Min GDP from this dataframe.

I tried

```
df.loc[df['GDP(BILLIONS)'].idxmax()]
```

but got an error message

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `error message` ?

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-50655e1c6fb4> in <module>()
----> 1 df.loc[df.columns['GDP(BILLIONS)'].idxmax()]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   4278         if is_scalar(key):
   4279             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key)
-> 4280             return getitem(key)
   4281 
   4282         if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

> Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis. NA/null values are excluded.

[Series.idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas.Series.idxmax):

> Return the row label of the maximum value.

You can use `idxmax` if you want to return the corresponding row values of max value, then **max value**

```
row_of_max_index = df.loc[df['GDP'].idxmax()] #series of max index row
print(row_of_max_index ) # 2   Algeria   227.80    DZA
print(row_of_max_index[2]) #index of GDP column to get 227.8
```

The same thing for [idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
row_of_min_index = df.loc[df['GDP'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: Glad to help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
max_val = df['GDP(BILLIONS)'].max()
```

for maximum value and

```
min_val = df['GDP(BILLIONS)'].min()
```

for minimum value